# Unity container, how to inject an specific class based on the "calling" class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I have the following snippet

```
 public static void RegisterComponents(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers
        container.RegisterType<ISocialClient, ClientA>("a");
        container.RegisterType<ISocialClient, ClientB>("b");
        container.RegisterType<ISocialClient, ClientC>("c");

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

this is WebApi2 project.
So I have 3 controllers,

```
public class SocialAController : ApiController
{
    private ISocialClient client;
    ...
}
```

Is there a way in Unity to configure, for SocialAController get the "ClientA" implementation, for SocialBController get the "ClientB" implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mspasiuk,

You can do this by registering for example SocialAController this way:

```
    container.RegisterType<SocialAController>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISocialClient>("a")));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
I have to add a constructor to the controller